# Exception when passing ref.watch for the authenticated user's email into a query

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, riverpod

I'm building a Flutter app with Amplify and Riverpod and when the user logs in, I want to check whether they have created a (separate) user profile entry in the DataStore. Depending on whether they have, I want to send them to the Homepage or to a page for creating a user profile.

On logging into the Flutter app (using Amplify Authenticator), the user is successfully directed to a 'HomePageLoader()' screen - however, if I try to pass in the user's email, I get an exception. If I hardcode the email then I find that on first signing in the result is always false. If I restart the app (with the user still logged in), I find the correct result is given.

**homepageloader_screen.dart**

```
class HomePageLoader extends ConsumerWidget {
  HomePageLoader({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final doesProfileExist = ref.watch(checkProfileExistsProvider);
    return doesProfileExist.when(
                loading: () => LoadingScreenFull(),
                error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
                data: (doesProfileExist) {
                  if(doesProfileExist == true) {
                    return HomePage();
                  } else {
                    return NewUserScreen();
                  }
                });
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is watching a provider, which will lookup the users email address to see if a record exists. You can see where I was hardcoding the email and where I have the email passed across.

There should only be one record, and this should then return a boolean for the above, that causes the user either to be sent to the homepage or to a screen where they are asked to complete a profile.

**providers.dart**

```
final emailAddressProvider = FutureProvider<String>((ref) {
  return EmailAddressProvider(ref);
});

Future<String> EmailAddressProvider(ref) async {
try {
      final result = await Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes();
      for (final element in result) {
        if(element.userAttributeKey.toString() == 'email') {
          debugPrint('User Email:');
          debugPrint(element.value.toString());
          return element.value.toString();
        }
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      // rethrow;
    }
    return 'No Email Found';
}


final checkProfileExistsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) {
  return checkProfileExists(ref);
});

Future<bool> checkProfileExists(ref) async {
  // final String email = 'example@email.example.com'; 
  final email = ref.watch(emailAddressProvider);
  final result = await Amplify.DataStore.query(Profile.classType, where: Profile.EMAIL.eq(email));
  debugPrint('Result length is: ${result.length}');
  debugPrint('Email that was searched: ${email}');
  if(result.length > 0) {
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument: Instance of 'AsyncData<String>'
```

In summary, my questions are:

1. What is happening to cause the incorrect return on first signing in (when I hardcode the email), but the correct response on restarting?
2. What's causing the error when I pass in the ref.watch for the authenticated user's email? I'm assuming something to do with the email not having been retrieved in time for the DataStore query?

Thanks in advance. I have done my best to interrogate the Flutter, AWS, and Riverpod docs, but am about ready to pull my hair out, so any help appreciated.